# How to find object in array by id number which is in another array in that object in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have array of movie objects. I am passing id of movie genre to my state trying to extract object by movie genre ids. The problem is that every object in that array of movie objects have property named genre_ids which is an another array of multiple ids, and I am passing just one. I am having problem of mapping or find proper object that has that passed id in it's property genre_id which is array of multiple ids...can anyone help?

Here is the method in my state in which I am stuck

```
movieByGenre (state) {
      return (genreId) => {
        return state.popularMovies.find((movie) => {
          movie.genreId.map((id) => {
            return id === genreId
          })
        })
      }
    }
```

Here is data structure of movies

[image]

Comment: `.find()` searches for the first item in collection which returns `true`. But your `.find()` returns `undefined` because it simply creates a `.map()`, without returning anything. You probably want to return whether or not that `.map()` includes a property of your `movie` param.

Comment: You're missing return statement inside `find` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your use case, something like this:

```
function movieByGenre(state) {
  return genreId => {
    const movies = state.popularMovies.filter(movie =>
      movie.genre_ids.includes(genreId)
    );

    return movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)];
  };
}
```

This uses [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only return movies that the given `genreId` is in that movie's `genre_ids` collection. You can then use that filtered collection to return a single movie however you'd like.

Comment: `filter` returns a collection, which doesn't seem to be what OP is after. I'd say the question needs more definition. As in, what does the collection look like and what should the state getter return.

Comment: The state getter should return object whos array have id which is passed to that state getter method, I hope I have elaborate this wright

Comment: All of them or only the first match?

Comment: first match, in other word if I am looking for drama movie in collections of movies I want to have random drama movie spit out from that collection

Comment: Ok, the first example didn't work, I will try with this one, I think this should work

Answer (score 0):

after trying this solution I get error message in console "Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined""

NOTE: this is hardcoded genre id just for testing things out, which I know exist in movie collection

This is my component code from which I am calling state getter method

```
<template>
  <p>{{movie.title}}</p>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  genreId: "18",

  computed: {
    movie() {
      return this.$store.getters.movieByGenre(this.genreId);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's just because, at first load, the `movie` object is `null`, thus you can't access `title` from `null`. You can try `{{ movie && movie.title }}`

Comment: I never seen this interpolation before :) but I will give it a Try
EDIT: nope, I still get the same error

Comment: Can you just `console.log(this.$store.getters.movieByGenre(this.genreId));` then?

Comment: It is undefined, so I think the state getter logic isn't good

Comment: Ok, so that's the problem. I'm not sure, but are you write the code `exactly` same as @Anthony answer?

Comment: Guys, the problem was fxxxx string type of genre_ids, Anthony's code is running after I changed string to number, OMG!
EDIT: my mistake, all along I was sending string!!!

Comment: Oh nice! I see. Type casting problem :')